# How to get last updated records from the record where i previously fetched last time

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

how to store last fetched record info in sql and how to pass the same condition in sql ? i'm having LastModifiedOn field in table (Using C#)

Comment: You can have datetime field in your table and query based on it.

Comment: you should include the design of your table in your question, also, where do you store the previously selected rows?

Comment: @GeomanYabes i will store those records in xml file

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

if your table doesn't have a `inserted_date` column (or something like that), I think the solution would be to

`SELECT * from table where ID not int(ALL_THE_IDS_OF_THE_ITEMS_IN_XML)`

But that will be a very coslty method since you need to parse your xml and retrieve all the IDs.

The best solution is to have an `inserted_date` column in your table then after your every select, you store the time at that current fetch. something like:

`SELECT *, getdate() as SelectDate from table`

you will then store that `SelectDate` somewhere so that it will be referenced on your next select:

**NOTE:** `SelectDate` reflects the actual time of your previous query.

`SELECT *, getdate() as SelectDate from table where inserted_date > 'YOUR_PREVIOUS_SelectDate'`

Accordingly, you just use the latest `SelectDate` for your next query.

Comment: How to send - Previous_SelectDate query dynamically ?

Comment: what language are you using? in c# it's something like: `string query = select * from table where inserted_date = '{0}'; query = string.Format(query, YOUR_DATE)`

Comment: you can store your `Previous_SelectDate` in your xml file then each time you run your query, you fetch that value from your xml then 
use that in your query. after your select, you update the `Previous_SelectDate` in your xml file with the result from your recent query.